# Sourcing ("dotting") shell script from Docker

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to set up a docker image that downloads `Phantomjs` and sets up the alias in `~/.bash_rc` and path in `~/.profile`. Below is the `Dockerfile` that does this.

```
FROM node:8.9.4

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

RUN wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 \
    && tar xvjf phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

RUN mv phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN  . usr/src/app/test.sh
RUN . ~/.bashrc
RUN . ~/.profile

EXPOSE 4219

CMD ["node_modules/casperjs/bin/casperjs","selftest"]
```

Also the script test.sh sets up the environment variable. Here are the contents of the script.

```
  #!/bin/sh

   echo "alias phantomjs='/usr/src/app/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs'" >> ~/.bashrc

   echo "PATH=\"$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH:/usr/src/app/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin\"" >> ~/.profile
```

But it returns this error now

```
 Step 10/16 : RUN . ~/.profile
    ---> Running in 87cdccc4fef7
    stdin: is not a tty
```

What should I do to make this script run?

Comment: afaik `source` command only works on bash shell. However, docker CMD will use /bin/sh shell by default. Fix: use `. ~/.bash_rc`.

Comment: looks like you are sourcing the wrong filename ...

Comment: @chenchuk good catch, instead of `source /test.sh`, he should execute the script by using `sh /test.sh`.

Comment: Step 9/11 : RUN  sh /test.sh
 ---> Running in d196dd140455
sh: 0: Can't open /test.sh
it still won't run

Comment: I can see you're copying the current directory inside /usr/src/app, if test script is inside of it just pass the whole path to sh. RUN sh /usr/src/app/test.sh

Comment: You create `~/.bashrc` in line 3 of test.sh and sourcing `~/.bash_rc` at line #4. Is  `~/.bash_rc` available?

Comment: @RobertRanjan I have edited the post and now I am getting the tty error.

Comment: @slackmart I did that and have edited the script. Yeah I missed the part where I had forgotten that I was sourcing bash_rc instead of bashrc. But I am facing a new issue now. When I try to source .profile it returns the error - stdin: is not a tty. All the edits to the script and Dockerfile are there in the main post.

Comment: I think there is no effect on running .profile and .bashrc towards the end of Dockerfile. You can remove them and give a try. Please share the command you are running as well.

Comment: Every time you have a RUN command, it runs in a new and different shell. Things you sourced into old shells don't apply to new ones.

Comment: `CMD ["bash", "-c", ". usr/src/app/test.sh; . ~/.bashrc; . ~/.profile; exec \"$@\"", "_", "node_modules/casperjs/bin/casperjs","selftest"]`. That said, to fix `not a tty`, you'll need to use the `-i` and `-t` arguments to `docker run`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So everything is working now. The only issue that remains now is that it is not sourcing the alias and path. When I login to the container and then source the bashrc and profile, it works. How do I make sure that when I run the CMD in Dockerfile. It sources the bashrc and profile.

Comment: `.bashrc` and `.profile` aren't honored for noninteractive shells -- they aren't *supposed* to work in this scenario. For the PATH, use the Docker `ENV` directive. And even if you source `.bashrc` into a noninteractive shell, aliases are turned off in noninteractive shells anyhow. You *could* use an exported function, but why aren't you just putting the directory containing`phantomjs` directly in the PATH and avoiding the need?